# Probability of rolling two $6$s with $15$ independent dice rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So there are $6^{15}$ outcomes in general. If we know that there has to be at least two $6$s in the outcomes, that means that we have $13$ more rolls that can be whatever, so is the answer simply $6^{13}$?

That doesn't sound right because, if we think of this as a list counting problem, then: we're making a $15$-element list out of a of $6$ options (which is how I got $6^{15}$). But two of the $15$ elements must be $6$, and there are $6^{13}$ different ways to choose a list with two $6$s.

However, the $6$ can be in any position in the list (the interpretation of this is that any two of the $15$ dice rolls can yield a $6$, so long as two of them do: it doesn't necessarily have to be the first two rolls, for example).

So how do we compensate for the fact that the two $6$s can appear anywhere in the list? It would result in the answer being greater than $6^{13}$, right?

Also, if there is perhaps a simpler way to think about this without bringing combinatorics into it, I'm all ears!

Comment: Are you finding the probability of rolling _at least_ two $6$s? ... or the probability of rolling _exactly_ two $6$s?  And in either case, do you know about the binomial distribution?

Comment: The answer for at least two sixes is pretty close to $1$.  The answer for exactly two sixes is smaller.  Which are you asking about?  The techniques for computing each are quite different.  Both involve combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

Let's count the complement; i.e., at most $1$ six is observed.  So either exactly $0$ sixes are rolled, or exactly $1$ six.  The first case is easy:  there are $5^{15}$ such outcomes.  The second case is a bit trickier but not much; first, there are $15$ ways to choose the die that is a six, and among the remaining $14$ dice, there are again $5^{14}$ ways to choose their values.  So the total number of such outcomes with exactly $1$ six is $$15 \cdot 5^{14}.$$  Therefore, the total number of outcomes with at most $1$ six is $$5^{15} + 15 \cdot 5^{14}.$$  So the desired probability is $$\frac{6^{15} - (5^{15} + 15 \cdot 5^{14})}{6^{15}}.$$

---

Note that the above calculation is naive in the sense that it does not assume familiarity with the binomial distribution; however, we can of course phrase the question in the context of such a distribution.  For the number of sixes observed is equivalent to the random number of successes in $n = 15$ independent trials (each trial consisting of a roll of a fair six-sided die, and success being rolling a six), in which the probability of success is $p = 1/6$.  The random number of sixes is a random variable $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 15, p = 1/6),$$ with probability mass function $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}, \quad x = 0, 1, \ldots, n.$$ hence $$\Pr[X \ge 2] = \sum_{x=2}^{15} \binom{15}{x} (1/6)^x (5/6)^{15-x} = 1 - \sum_{x=0}^1 \binom{15}{x} (1/6)^x (5/6)^{15-x} = 1 - \frac{15 \cdot 5^{15}}{6^{15}} - \frac{1}{6^{15}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a case of probability binomial distribution.
Probability of getting 6 in a throw is p = 1/6
Probability of not getting 6 in a throw is q =5/6
Probability of at least 2 time 6 is $$ P(r\geqslant2)=1-P(r=0)-P(r=1) $$
$$ P(r\geqslant2)=1-{15\choose 0}(\frac{5}{6})^{15}- {15\choose1}((\frac{5}{6})^{14})(\frac{1}{6})
 $$